# textbox is not editable after a click

Tags: html, asp.net, css, webforms

i have problem textbox is not editable after a single click. I have to make double to click to write in it. On single click it cursor goes to upper text box. How to remove it. please help me.
Thanks in advance

code is here

```
<form id="form1" class="form-style" method="post" runat="server">
    <label> Area(in Sq Ft)
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txtarea" ValidationGroup="1"> 
    <img alt="" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/erroricon.png")%>' />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtarea" runat="server">    
     Region 
    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtregion" runat="server">
     Name
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtName" ErrorMessage="Enter Your Name" ValidationGroup="1"> <img
    alt="" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/erroricon.png")%>' />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server">   
    Mobile No.
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtmobile" runat="server">     
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{10}" ControlToValidate="txtmobile" ErrorMessage="Incorrect Number" ValidationGroup="1">
    <img alt="" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/erroricon.png")%>' />
    <asp:Button ID="Btnsave" runat="server" Text="Send" Width="78px" Style="color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; background: url(../images/button-1.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x #08489f;border-top: #339ed3 1px solid; border-right: #2881c3 1px solid; border-bottom: #1a62b1 1px solid;border-left: #2881c3 1px solid; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none;padding: 5px 21px 7px 19px; cursor: pointer;" OnClick="Btnsave_Click" ValidationGroup="1" />    
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black">
     </label>
</form>
```

it is css

```
.form-style .jqTransformHidden {
    display:none;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper {
    position:relative;
    height:21px;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:#8e8e8e;
    font-size:12px;
    height:31px;
    background:url(../images/select.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x #ececec;
    border:1px solid #cecece;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper div {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:#8e8e8e;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:15px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper div span {
    display:block;
    width:100% !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:7px 3px 9px 25px;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper a.jqTransformSelectOpen {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    height:31px;
    width:29px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    background:url(../images/select.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    border-left:#d5d5d5 1px solid;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper div:hover a.jqTransformSelectOpen {
    background-position:right 0;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul {
        position:absolute;
        top:31px;
        left:-1px;
        background:#ececec;
        display:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        overflow:auto;
        overflow-y:auto;
        z-index:10;
        border:1px solid #cecece;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul a {
    display:block;
    color:#8e8e8e;
    padding-left:25px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:20px;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul a.selected {
    color:#929291;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li:hover {
    background:#fff;
}
.form-style .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a.selected:hover {
    color: #929291;
}
```

Comment: @user2768263 -  MelanciaUK means to share with us the code

Comment: its a css ehich is applying.form-bg {background:url(../images/form-bg.gif) 0 0 repeat; float:left; margin:36px 0 0 0; width:289px;}
.form-bg>strong {display:block; background:#363636; font-size:20px; line-height:24px; font-weight:normal; color:#fefefe; padding:7px 10px 10px 10px; text-align:center;}

Comment: Edit the question & add the css there, instead of as a comment my friend

Comment: Mlefevre i have posted now have a look

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..I have fixed it..works fine

```
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txtarea" ValidationGroup="1"> 

  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator> <img alt="" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/erroricon.png")%>' />
  <asp:TextBox ID="Txtarea" runat="server" placeholder="Area(in Sq Ft)">    
  </asp:TextBox> 
  <asp:TextBox ID="Txtregion" runat="server" placeholder="Region">
   </asp:TextBox> 
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtName" ErrorMessage="Enter Your Name" ValidationGroup="1"> 
   <img alt="" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/erroricon.png")%>' />
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
   <asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server" placeholder="Name">   
   </asp:TextBox> 
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtmobile" runat="server" placeholder="Mobile No."></asp:TextBox>     
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{10}" ControlToValidate="txtmobile" ErrorMessage="Incorrect Number" ValidationGroup="1">
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator> 
 <img alt="" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/erroricon.png")%>' />
 <asp:Button ID="Btnsave" runat="server" Text="Send" Width="78px" Style="color: #fff;
 font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; background: url(../images/button-1.jpg) 0 0     repeat-x #08489f;border-top: #339ed3 1px solid; border-right: #2881c3 1px solid; border-bottom: #1a62b1 1px solid;border-left: #2881c3 1px solid; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none;padding: 5px 21px 7px 19px; cursor: pointer;" OnClick="Btnsave_Click" ValidationGroup="1" />    

 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black">
  </asp:Label>
```